# Assigning formula to variable vs performing calulation in-line changes the outcome of my script using a while loop. Why?

Tags: python, while-loop, variable-assignment

I've encountered a problem that I think is related not to an error in my equation, but to the way that Python processes information. I don't understand and I'm hoping that someone can explain.

The following is a problem from MIT OCW 6.0001 in which a program calculates the number of months it will take to save for someone's dream home. The problem assumes that we invest carefully and achieve a rate of return of 4% annually on our savings. This is the variable `r`. The program should pass a test case by producing the result 183 months when the user inputs: 120000, .1, and 1000000.

This is my first attempt at the solution:

```
annual_salary = (float(input("What is your starting annual salary?")))
portion_saved = (annual_salary * (float(input("What porportion of your annual salary will you save? Please enter a percentage as a decimal:"))))/12
total_cost = (float(input("What is the cost of your dream home?")))

portion_down_payment = total_cost * 0.25
current_savings = 0.0
r = 0.04
monthly_return = ((current_savings*r)/12)
months = 0.0

while current_savings < portion_down_payment:
    current_savings += portion_saved + monthly_return
    months += 1
print("Number of months:", months)
```

It does not pass the test case. and I've narrowed down the problem to the `monthly_return` function. If I run a test by printing the `monthly_return`,`while months < 2`:

```
annual_salary = (float(input("What is your starting annual salary?")))
portion_saved = (annual_salary * (float(input("What porportion of your annual salary will you save? Please enter a percentage as a decimal:"))))/12
total_cost = (float(input("What is the cost of your dream home?")))

portion_down_payment = total_cost * 0.25
current_savings = 0.0
r = 0.04
monthly_return = ((current_savings*r)/12)
months = 0.0

while months < 2:
    current_savings += portion_saved + monthly_return
    months += 1
print("Number of months:", months)
print(monthly_return)
```

I find that the return is equal to 0.0.

However, if I simply remove the variable I've created for calculating `monthly_return`, and instead paste the formula contained within it into its space in the script, not only will I find that it passes the test case, but the monthly return calculation will also return ~6.68 while `months < 2`.

```
annual_salary = (float(input("What is your starting annual salary?")))
portion_saved = (annual_salary * (float(input("What porportion of your annual salary will you save? Please enter a percentage as a decimal:"))))/12
total_cost = (float(input("What is the cost of your dream home?")))

portion_down_payment = total_cost * 0.25
current_savings = 0.0
r = 0.04
months = 0.0

while months < 2:
    current_savings += portion_saved + ((current_savings*r)/12)
    months += 1
print("Number of months:", months)
print(((current_savings*r)/12))
```

I have to believe that what's happening here has something to do with the way that Python is reading each variable while executing the `while` loop, but I don't understand what's happening or why. Can you please explain?

Comment: Python is an imperative programming language which means that statements are executed one after another. This means that your *variable* `monthly_return` is assigned once and when referred to never changes value. (You seem to think it is a *function* which is not true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update those values in the while loop:

```py
# Example data
annual_salary = 120000.0
portion_saved = annual_salary * (0.1)/12
total_cost = 1000000.0

portion_down_payment = total_cost * 0.25
current_savings = 0.0
r = 0.04
months = 0.0

while current_savings < portion_down_payment:
    portion_down_payment = total_cost * 0.25
    monthly_return = ((current_savings*r)/12)
    current_savings += portion_saved + monthly_return
    months += 1
print("Number of months:", months)
```

Outputs:

```
Number of months: 183.0
```

---

Because the values `portion_down_payment` and `monthly_return` need to be updated on each iteration of the while loop. Rather than being assigned once.

Comment: Thank you! I have a better understanding now. For instance, It looks like ```portion_down_payment = total_cost * 0.25``` can actually be removed from the loop because it's a fixed number and doesn't change through each iteration. But ```monthly_return``` needs to be included in the loop or else it's calculating 4% return on ```current_savings``` which is set to zero where it is defined outside the loop. I'm still having difficulty understanding the relationship between the loop, ```current_savings```, and ```monthly_return``` but I will keep practicing.

Comment: No worries man , if this answer solves your question, I would appreciate it if you mark it as answered. And always feel free to keep asking questions here as well, good luck with Python!